# Dynamically remove a choice option from a form

Tags: django

I have a form like this:

```
RANGE_CHOICES = (
    ('last', 'Last Year'),
    ('this', 'This Year'),
    ('next', 'Next Year'),
)   

class MonthlyTotalsForm(forms.Form):
    range = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RANGE_CHOICES, initial='this')
```

It's displayed in the template like this:

```
{{ form.range }}
```

In some situations I don't want to show the 'Next Year' option. Is it possible to remove this option in the view where the form is created?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class MonthlyTotalsForm(forms.Form):
    range = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RANGE_CHOICES, initial='this')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        no_next_year = kwargs.pop('no_next_year', False)
        super(MonthlyTotalsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if no_next_year:
            self.fields['range'].choices = RANGE_CHOICES[:-1]

#views.py
MonthlyTotalsForm(request.POST, no_next_year=True)
```

Comment: I don't have edit privs, but you're missing a colon after method definition. Thanks for your answer!